# How to make the two buttons at the same level?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I followed the code using bootstrap Modal to create the two buttons shown below. I do not understand why they are displayed at different heights.

Does anyone know if it is because of my machine or other reasons? I have the css bootstrap setting in the layout. Is there still something missing?

[image: buttons mismatched height]

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Post?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <form action="{{ url_for('delete_post', post_id=post.id) }}" method="POST">
                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float or display to get this 2 work!

For example I used float:left to do so.

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Post?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float:left;">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" style="float:left;">Close</button>
            <form action="{{ url_for('delete_post', post_id=post.id) }}" method="POST">
                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just fix that with margin! Like: margin-top: -30px;